# Wanted: GPS-Track (gpx) Analyzer for Linux

Tags: linux, gps

I'm looking for a nice tool for Linux to get statistics out of a GPX track. Most important is total length, but also average speed in different section, height difference etc. would be useful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just stumbled upon your question. This guy here has written a program in .NET that seems to be pretty good. I'll try to see if I can get it to run on linux when I get back home.  http://www.gps-freeware.de/Download.aspx

Comment: Alright, i tried it. Could not extract the installer directly, so tried to install it using Wine. Installing went fine, but the tool detected the resolution wrong both in wine and with mono, and it was throwing exceptions all over the place. Sorry I could not help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Viking](http://sourceforge.net/projects/viking/) - it handles GPX files. I've used it myself and it works very well.